# Php Thank you Message in same page

Tags: php, forms, validation, email

I have to validate a form and send an email..I copied this form from w3schools and attached mailto function.But i dont know how to display "Thank you for submitting" After the form is processed. Kindly Help.. The Thank you message should display on the same page below Submit Button.

Here is my code..

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .error {color: #FF0000;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body> 

    <?php
    // define variables and set to empty values
    $nameErr = $emailErr = $genderErr = $websiteErr = "";
    $name = $email = $gender = $comment = $website = "";

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
       if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
         $nameErr = "Name is required";
       } else {
         $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
         // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
         if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
           $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
         }
       }

       if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
         $emailErr = "Email is required";
       } else {
         $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
         // check if e-mail address is well-formed
         if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
           $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
         }
       }

       if (empty($_POST["website"])) {
         $website = "";
       } else {
         $website = test_input($_POST["website"]);
         // check if URL address syntax is valid (this regular expression also allows dashes in the URL)
         if (!preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$website)) {
           $websiteErr = "Invalid URL"; 
         }
       }

       if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {
         $comment = "";
       } else {
         $comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
       }

       if (empty($_POST["gender"])) {
         $genderErr = "Gender is required";
       } else {
         $gender = test_input($_POST["gender"]);
       }
    }

    function test_input($data) {
       $data = trim($data);
       $data = stripslashes($data);
       $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
       return $data;
    }


    ?>

    <h2>PHP Form Validation Example</h2>
    <p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"> 
       Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
       <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
       <br><br>
       E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
       <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
       <br><br>
       Website: <input type="text" name="website" value="<?php echo $website;?>">
       <span class="error"><?php echo $websiteErr;?></span>
       <br><br>
       Comment: <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"><?php echo $comment;?></textarea>
       <br><br>
       Gender:
       <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="female") echo "checked";?>  value="female">Female
       <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="male") echo "checked";?>  value="male">Male
       <span class="error">* <?php echo $genderErr;?></span>
       <br><br>
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
    </form>


    <?php
    $to = "dheeraj.narayan1712@gmail.com";
    $subject = "My subject";
    $name = "Name: $name";
    $email = "$email";
    $headers = "From: webmaster@example.com" . "\r\n" .
    "CC: somebodyelse@example.com";

    mail($to,$subject,$name,$headers);
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are just required to edit your code in the below given manner.
if(!mail($to,$subject,$name,$headers))
{
          echo " Some thing Went Wrong";
}
else
{
       echo " Successfully, Thanks !!!!";
}

Comment: I don't understand where you want your message to be shown. Try this: `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onClick="alert('Thank you for submitting!')">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's rather simple;

```
if(isset($email)){
   echo 'Success! Thanks for submitting';
}
```

And then just place it after the mail function? Notice that you can change $email to any of the POST variables that you want, and also change the echo'ed content. (if you want to place it inside of the form remember to wrap it in

```
<?php ?>
```